# How to export a program from windows to ubuntu app for windows?

Tags: software-installation, windows-10

I'm using the app for Ubuntu that is available for windows 10, I don't know how to export a program from my downloads folder in windows to the Ubuntu environment. 
Does anyone know how to do this?

I will appreciate your help.

Nayeli

Answer (score 0):

In your Ubuntu shell (bash for windows, etc) you can navigate to `/mnt/c/Users/[username]/Downloads` to get to your downloads folder.

Comment: Thanks I tried to do that but it doesn't accept the user name, it says that: No such file or directory. So, I did one by one and using cd and ls commands but the result is the same, I'm seeing the directory and is highlighted in green but I can't choose it. I don't know if this is because my user name has two words (Nay EC).

Comment: To enter a directory name containing a space you can  put a backslash before the space. For example: `cd Nay\ EC` should work